# Custom tabs in jtextarea in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent, styleddocument, defaultstyleddocument

How to set tab stops in jtextarea for different lengths,

first tab should stop 4

Second tab should stop at 20 (If i give tab from 4 it should stop at 20)

Third tab should stop at 30 (If i give tab from 0 it should stop at 30)

Comment: No tabbing system works like you described.  In the tabbing systems I'm familiar with, the cursor would go from 0 to 4 to 20 to 30 to the next line on subsequent presses of the Tab key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
StyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument():

SimpleAttributeSet attributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();

TabStop[] tabStops = new TabStop[3];
tabStops[0] = new TabStop(4.0, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_DOTS);
tabStops[1] = new TabStop(20.0, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_DOTS);
tabStops[2] = new TabStop(30.0, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_DOTS);

TabSet tabSet = new TabSet(tabStops);
StyleConstants.setTabSet(attributes, tabSet);
document.setParagraphAttributes(0, 0, attributes, false);
```

When you create the `JTextArea`, use the `Document` constructor.

Comment: I have experienced problems when using tap stops at fractional positions. Notice that tap stop is a float value. So, I have used Math.rint() to round the tap stop position to the closest integer value.